# RapidMiner replace zero number with a "missing value"

Tags: data-mining, rapidminer

I have a dataset that has lots of zeros, but I want to remove the zeros and instead replace them with a missing value or a NaN value. I've tried using RapidMiner operators:

- Map
- Replace Replace missing values
- Replace all missings

and none of them are working the way I expected to.

Answer (score 1):

to replace a zero (0), or any other regular value, with a missing value, you can use the [**Declare Missing Value**](https://docs.rapidminer.com/latest/studio/operators/cleansing/missing/declare_missing_value.html) operator. You can specify a given value (like 0) or even declare an expression, for example `att_1 < 10` so all values of the column att_1 that are below 10 are declared as missing.